# Conditional Rendering in .NET MAUI

Tags: maui

I am using .NET MAUI to build a mobile app and I am facing some issues. Essentially what I want to achieve is to get a different view each time a user logs in, depending on a variable in some object called the UserLoanAccount. I am currently struggling with this and it's been about two to three weeks where I haven't been able to deliver this feature. Might be due to a lack of understanding.

The app has a bottom navigation bar that I created using the TabBar inside of the AppShell.xaml. Like so:

`<TabBar> <ShellContent Route="Page1" Icon="home" Title="Home" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:Page1}" /> <ShellContent Route="Page2" Icon="card" Title="Product" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:Page2}" /> <ShellContent Route="Page3" Icon="profile" Title="Profile" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:Page3}" /> </TabBar>`

Initially we had the pages rendering by using a TemplateSelector. The rendering worked but one of the pages has a CollectionView of Products that when clicked, is supposed to send users to a ViewProducts page. When using the TemplateSelector, when users click on the Product in the list, they get no response and the product is just highlighted in orange.

Then we moved on to using ContentTemplates, which worked fine but anytime we visit the Page1, the ViewProducts page just pops up without being called, and has 0 values for the items being passed into that page from the CollectionView of Products

I would like some help and I can answer any further questions

Comment: You’ve described two different problems without providing any meaningful details about either of them.  Pick one, supply the relevant code and details, then we can help you solve it

Comment: Could you please share the code about how you use TemplateSelector  or a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help us reproduce this issue? By the way, did you mean this issue : [DataTemplateSelector on CollectionView is completely broken - templates don't match BindingContext](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12988)?